# Bulding only GCC backend without building other components

Tags: gcc, backend, compiler-optimization, gnu

I would like to build GCC backend with minimum dependencies without building other components, can I get the steps for the same please.

I am trying to build gcc backend but in order to build entire gcc compiler we need to have multiple libs, once of them being,GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library, as dependencies. Is there a way to by pass this and build only GCC backend? I got the following error while trying to configure,

```
configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 3.1.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
```

I don't want to build these libs for GCC backend(unless they are components of backend). any help is appreciated.

Comment: GCC's optimizer needs bigint and big-FP for constant-propagation while optimizing C and C++ code.  I don't expect there's any way to get around this or build a reduced-feature GCC, or one that introduces rounding errors sometimes.  Of course you don't have to build those libraries from source, installing them from binary packages should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot build the compiler (proper) without host libraries. Maybe read GCC's [install documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) again?

There are basically two ways to get the host libs:

1. Build the host libs like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/) etc. with the compiler.  This is very nice when you are building a canadian cross or are shipping the compiler so it has no external dependencies. Also required if your host has other versions of these libs than you want to use with GCC. To that end:

   - Download the GCC sources.
   - `cd` to the GCC toplevel source directory.
   - Run `./contrib/download_prerequisites`. This will download external host lib sources to GCC source tree and add soft-links, see [Downloading GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/download.html).
   - Run `configure` and `make` as usual.
2. Install GMP, MPFR etc. on the host and provide them to configure by means of `--with-gmp=`, `--with-gmp-include=`, `.--with-gmp-lib=` etc., see [Installing GCC: Configuration](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html).